# How facebook did?

Tags: php, html, facebook

I open link picture in a web browser.

```
https://scontent-kul1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p160x160/13118912_115282595548678_4700279271527942633_n.jpg?oh=8e48da98ba4f892a1619e50515a66bfd&oe=5832B63C
```

Delete the parameters:

```
oh=8e48da98ba4f892a1619e50515a66bfd&oe=5832B63C
```

And reload the link

```
https://scontent-kul1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p160x160/13118912_115282595548678_4700279271527942633_n.jpg
```

Nothing to display.

How they do the magic trick?

Comment: what kind of a question is this? and without codes?

Comment: ya try to be smart here.

Comment: I hate it when this types of questions are downvoted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Ghost What do you need the code for, LOL? The question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you investigate Facebook's response, you will find out that what you get with oh parameter missing, is *403 (Forbidden)* status with `text/plain` Content-Type.

I don't know what is this `oh` parameter for, but it looks like some kind of security hash. If you skip it or change it - the effect is Forbidden status.

Please keep in mind that image responses don't need to come from image files. In web, everything is just request and response. Facebook serves those images through a script, which just happens to output image content with appropriate Content-Type.